# What are all the ways to introduce local variables in JavaScript and what do they bind?

Tags: javascript, variables, local, static-analysis

I'm writing a static analyzer for JavaScript and I have to keep track of all of the local variables at any point of the code. What are all the ways to introduce new local variables to the scope in JavaScript?

Comment: Note: I'm asking & answering this question as initially I didn't know about catch clause, and I forgot about `arguments`, so I figured it would be nice to have this all in one place. I'm also wondering if I missed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are all the ones I have identified so far:

- The standard library includes the following global variables: `Array Boolean Date Function Number Object RegExp String Error EvalError RangeError ReferenceError SyntaxError TypeError URIError decodeURI decodeURIComponent encodeURI encodeURIComponent eval isFinite isNaN parseFloat parseIn Infinity JSON Math NaN undefined`.
- Variable declarations introduce a variable in the scope. e.g. `var a, b, c, d=4`.

  - Note that variable declarations are all lifted. e.g. `function () { foob(x); var x = 12; }` is functionally equivalent to `function () { var x; foob(x); x = 12; }`
- Function statements and expressions. These not only bind the argument list but also create a local `arguments` variable.

  - Note that function statements are also lifted, e.g. `function () { funcstatement(12); if (false) { function funcstatement(y) { y + 4; } } }` is functionally equivalent to `function () { function funcstatement(y) { y + 4; }; funcstatement(12); if (false) {}; }`
- Named function expressions introduce the name in the scope of the function, e.g. `var x = function name() { /* 'name' available here */ }`.
- `try {} catch (e) {}` introduces the variable `e` only in the scope of the catch clause.

Comment: `function <name> { }` creates a local binding of `<name>`.

Comment: To expand on `function`, the function declaration statement introduces the function name as a local variable in the enclosing scope (the scope where the declaration occurs), and *also* as a local binding inside the declared function. A function instantiation expression with a name similarly binds the name *inside* the created function, but not outside (except in buggy runtimes like old IE).

Comment: @Barmar: good one! @Pointy: I don't think function statement introduces it in the local scope. If I do `function sup() { sup = null; }; sup()`, then the `sup` in the outer scope does get set to `null`. if it were a local binding then it wouldn't affect the outer scope

Comment: @Claudiu the binding in the local scope (inside the created function) is supposed to be immutable.  [See section 13 of the spec.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13) It doesn't appear to be the case that Spidermonkey or V8 implement that correctly.

Comment: Also noting `function () { funcstatement(12); if (false) { function funcstatement(y) { y + 4; } } }`, it is actually erroneous to declare a function inside a statement or block. Seed pg 86. of [the spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) (pdf).

Comment: @Pointy: unless I'm misreading it, I think that only applies to named function expressions, not function statements. e.g. `var x = function foob() { foob = null; console.log(foob); }`, which works properly in V8 - `foob` still refers to the function itself even after the assignment

Comment: @Claudiu you may be right. It does seem to work for function expressions however.  I'll post an answer about it because it's hard to put stuff here :)

Comment: @Wyatt: thanks, I had forgotten about that. i suppose it's up to me as the writer of the static analysis to either disallow it or try to do something sensible

Answer (score 1):

Function expressions (and not function declaration statements) bind the (optional) function name to the environment *inside* the created function (but not outside).  Here's a test:

```
function f1() {
  function f2(n) {
    if (n) {
      f2 = null;
      f2(0);
    }
    else
      console.log("f2");
  }
  f2(1);
  console.log(typeof f2);
}

f1();
```

That'll throw an error because overriding "f2" with `null` updates the value of the symbol "f2" in the outer ("f1") scope.  Now, this variation:

```
function f1() {
  var f2 = function f2(n) {
    if (n) {
      f2 = null;
      f2(0);
    }
    else
      console.log("f2");
  }
  f2(1);
  console.log(typeof f2);
}

f1();
```

That works (logging first "f2" and then "function").  The assignment to "f2" throws no error but it doesn't do anything, because the name "f2" is bound as an immutable property of the scope.  The assignment affects neither the inner "f2" nor the outer "f2".